# Whats the minimum amount of up votes/down votes that can be tracked by the system to be reversed in next 24 hours?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes, serial-voting

I want to know that what is the minimum amount of up votes/down votes which can be detected by the system which can be reversed in 24 hours?

I think its *three* because I confirmed with two mods, but if its that so than I think there's a bug in the system.

I've asked this question because yesterday, I received 4 serial down votes (in a minute) on top answers of mine *(so obviously seems hatred votes)* so well, not complaining about them but they were not reversed by the system.

Sometimes it also happens that a user gets over happy with some posts of mine and knowingly up vote the answers, also, they are not reversed in certain scenarios, so just want to know the floor limit of the system to detect the serial vote pattern for both, up votes as well as down votes.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien?tab=reputation) / Image -

[image]

Comment: This is not public info. I also strongly suspect it depends on the nature if the voting (timings, other votes cast by the voter, etc.)

Comment: Whatever the formula is, it's definitely a lot more lax for upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: per my testing, [minimal amount is 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773 "discussed in more details here"): "it is most likely that vote reversal script uses some data about prior abuse... the guy who serially voted you once, will have harder time trying it next time, even if they vote less..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The amount of votes necessary to trigger the serial voting cleanup is intentionally kept secret, to prevent people from abusing the system by skimming it's borders.

Basically, "no-one" knows exactly how far they can go.

It's likely factors like a user's history, the amount of votes, the timespan of these votes, the type of votes and probably some factors I'm forgetting about are considered. Exactly **how** is a secret stored in a [dwarf star alloy](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarf_star_alloy) vault.

Comment: This is indeed the case. Not even us moderators know the exact criteria.

Answer (score 4):

If you find a case where it appears that the serial vote reversal script has missed something flag one of the posts for moderator attention and we'll investigate - well ask one of the Community Managers to investigate and see if it warrants a manual invalidation of the votes.

As Cerbrus says the details are deliberately kept vague to prevent people gaming the system.

Comment: kewl, I also had the serial upvote issue previously with the colleagues who deliberately voted random post for a while which were then managed by Gordon, so was just curious to know what are the real rules for the cron job to detect suspicious votes. Thanks for the info though...