# When does downvoting get "serial" enough to be worth reporting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

The question is as in the title. One vote obviously can't be serial. A couple dozen of votes in 1 minute obviously are. Still, as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275330/719662

> 2 votes against you from one person generally is not seen as a serial vote by the system.

and, as per [What happens when vote fraud gets past the script?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255312/what-happens-when-vote-fraud-gets-past-the-script/255347#255347), quote

> We get a lot of people who get two or three downvotes and then go off flagging their post complaining about "serial downvoting" - this is pretty much a waste of everyone's time.

Maybe it's a waste of time, maybe it ain't. Story time:

It has happened to me a couple of times during the last few years that I got serial-downvoted with 2-3 vote packs. The "culprits" were completely different users, yet the *modus operandi* was the same: they were well aware that more votes would trigger the script (AFAIR in one case it was user's 2nd attempt, after a previous vote reversal by script), so they waited a some time, about a week, after an initial disagreement with me, and then threw two or three votes on my questions (there ain't many of them, and I seldom get downvotes, so the results are quite visible to me) in rapid succession.

The story ends here. Those users obviously "got their revenge", and, as of today, all left me alone after that. I haven't been able to connect the dots till I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227845/undetectable-micro-serial-downvoting-what-is-it-what-to-do-what-the-heck) - thankfully, none of the people who downvoted me were persistent enough to do what Andrea describes vs me - but I noticed [A downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away) and came to a conclusion. (also, thanks to `gnat` I also found [Spiteful downvoting? Two fast DVs to my unrelated posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773))

Current voting-reversal system is well known to people. Since they know it, they can game it - and they do. OTOH, my opinion is, that if we *allow* (per written or unwritten rules) **any** kind of serial downvoting to happen (be it 2 or 3 votes in sequence), we're basically saying "yeah, you can serial-downvote people, but you have to do it gracefully & patiently, so that we won't have to act against you on the grounds of *not wasting our time*" - this just enables the user to repeat it, and since he *can* game the rules, he *will* repeat this behaviour, sooner or later.

Still, I'm not a mod nor a community admin, and that's only my personal opinion.

So, the *exact* question goes as follows:

> (assuming the downvoting bothers me for whatever reason) *when* should I raise the mod flag or send a community report, so that it won't be considered "a waste of (moderator) time" or "not a pattern, due to being a single occurrence of user's action"?

Comment: The limit is not going to be revealed, because once it is, people can easily do just enough to not cross the threshold. As for when to flag, this is brought up in other answers about serial voting, _including in the [faq post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)_

Comment: @Kendra people already *do so* - that's why I'm asking *when should I report*, not *what's the limit*. Also, I've read the FAQ and related posts a couple of times, and find no clear indication of answer to my problem.

Comment: Your title asks (indirectly) what the limit is. And I was finding the answer to "when should I report" as that's been answered before.

Comment: @Kendra *sigh* IFTFY, I've added the missing two words to the title.

Comment: Yes, I've had these little packets of 2 downvotes too.  Since they are on old, dead questions of mine and both happened at the same time, it's obviously malicious.  I don't particularly care about -4, but it must be intensely annoying to lower rep users:(  Not sure what could be done..

Comment: If you don't see in the faq what your answer is, allow me to point it out for you. _"...but if in the unlikely event it doesn't clear them all **wait 24 hours** and should any suspicious down-votes remain flag one of the posts for moderator attention using the "other" option and explain what happened."_ (emphasis original)

Comment: @Kendra I've done that, and received "Sorry, but I don't see any obvious pattern here." (in the exact case of the flag raised to the last encounter of this)

Comment: If that's what the mods answered, then they looked into it and saw no signs of a voting pattern. They have tools to see more information about it than we do.

Comment: @vaxquis - in that case it probably wasn't a pattern. If it happens again it may well indicate that has *become* a pattern and as such it will be dealt with.

Comment: @Kendra I understood it as "two votes ain't a serial pattern"

Comment: @MartinJames it's a well known thing, see [Spiteful downvoting? Two fast DVs to my unrelated posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773)

Comment: @gnat thank you for your link, good to see the problem *was* raised elsewhere too!

Comment: I've been targeted several times by slow-voters.  Because, you know, I'm a complete a-hole and totally deserve it.  None of them however ever kept it up for more than two months.  It does require true dedication to teaching, not many have the patience or the aptitude.

Comment: @HansPassant I honestly tried using the *persistent* approach before; there was a time in my life when I thought I'll be able to outlive all people who are trying (or succeeding) in making my life miserable. Then, one day, I realized that most of those people are half my age. That thought really scared the crap of me... it came to me that it'll probably be the other way around; intelligence requires maintenance, stupidity doesn't.

The only "gaming" solution on SO seems to not ask any questions... seems that having none (or almost none) deters most of the hottest revenge-voting heads.

Comment: You got a downvote yesterday and one in June. This post was from a year ago, and there is a conspiracy going on again that you edit your question above near its anniversary? :p

Comment: @Drew http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/308632/8 - I've edited the question only because it was edited by Josh and, while I'm greatly thankful for his grammar corrections, I considered two changes he did superfluous. As for the DV I got - it's on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily/29459402#29459402 ; for some reason, regardless of the usefulness of the answer and the disclaimer I put, some people consider that "This is a dangerous answer.". I didn't get "serial minidownvoting" again, FWIW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the minimum amount of up votes/down votes that can be tracked by the system to be reversed in next 24 hours?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267873/whats-the-minimum-amount-of-up-votes-down-votes-that-can-be-tracked-by-the-syste)

Comment: Not a dupe. It does not address the specific question at the bottom of this post.

Comment: I agree with @JanDoggen - voting to Leave Open. The other question asks when the _system_ considers it serial downvoting, which is deliberately kept secret. This question is when _we_ should report suspicious downvoting.

Answer (score 8):

We have more tools available to us that just the "serial voting" scripts. While these find (and reverse) the most egregious cases of serial voting without the need for human interaction there are cases that slip through or are being done in such a way to attempt to avoid the scripts.

When we find such cases the votes are invalidated and the user warned about their behaviour.

If you think that you are being targeted then raise a flag on one of your posts and we'll look into it and deal with it appropriately. However, given the size of Stack Overflow there is no way that anyone (including moderators) could say that "two or three votes cast on the exact same time" are a pattern or not. Yes they could be, but by the "law of averages" it could be three different people voting at the same time.

A single incident could be just a coincidence. However, if it's repeated several times then it's starting to look more like a pattern. Please don't be so quick to assume that every down-vote is part of a campaign against you.

Comment: speaking of *averages* - on SO, I've got a total of *4* downvotes on *all* my questions, covering the last 4 & half year. Of those 4, *2* were cast at the exact same time, a couple of days after I replied to a downvoter on one of my answers. Should I calculate the chance that of the ~2365000 minutes of my SO activity, two random people select the first two of my questions, each one selects the other, and completely randomly cast those two on the *exact same minute*?

Comment: Of course it's malicious, I'd stake my rep on it, (assuming the serial downvoters leave me with any:).

Comment: So in other words, moderators dont give enough care if someone has lost like 10 points by serial downvoting just because its not a pattern